# Median with Postgres 9.4 - Why isn't my code working?

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

```
SELECT 
(users.created_at::timestamp - invitations.created_at::timestamp) as elapsed,
percentile_disc(0.50)
      WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY elapsed) as median
 FROM invitations
 join users on users.id = invitations.user_id
```

Trying to find out the median wait time between the creation of an invitation and the acceptance of it by the user. This code generates an error:

```
ERROR: column "elapsed" does not exist.
```

How can I repair it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an alias on the same level where you define it. You need to wrap this in a derived table:

```
select elapsed, 
       percentile_disc(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY elapsed) as median
from (
  SELECT users.created_at::timestamp - invitations.created_at::timestamp as elapsed,
  FROM invitations
    join users on users.id = invitations.user_id
) t;
```